How to prove that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi\right)=1$?
How to prove that
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi\right)=1$$
?

Maybe use $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$.

The standard decomposition of the sine of sums is
$$
\sin(\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi)
= 
\sin(\frac{k}{n}\pi)\cos(\frac{1}{2n}\pi)
-\cos(\frac{k}{n}\pi)\sin(\frac{1}{2n}\pi).
$$
In addition by the formulas 1.342.1 and 1.342.2 in
the Gradsteyn-Ryzhik tables
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx) = \sin (\frac{n+1}{2}x)\sin\frac{nx}{2} cosec\frac{x}{2}
$$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \cos(kx) = \cos (\frac{n+1}{2}x)\sin\frac{nx}{2} cosec\frac{x}{2}+1
$$
